# minesweeper game logic problem (fetching another components props from a component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, minesweeper

I'm new to React and I'm trying to grasp the broad strokes by building a simple minesweeper game.  I'm able to render a 10x10 board (Grid), and reveal squares (Square).  However, I've hit a wall with the step in which multiple squares are revealed with a single click.

The way I've written it (I think) requires a square component to know if the surrounding square components have a mine.  How should I go about this?  Or am I writing it in a way that isn't really consistent with React's intended use?

Code:

```
----------
Grid.js
----------

import React from 'react';
import Square from './Square';

export default function Grid(props) {
    const grid = new Array(10);
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        grid[i] = new Array(10).fill(null);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {
                grid.map((row, x) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={x}>
                            {
                                row.map((col, y) => {
                                    const randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
                                    return (
                                        <Square
                                            row={x}
                                            col={y}
                                            id={`square-${x}-${y}`}
                                            key={`square-${x}-${y}`}
                                            hasMine={randInt === 0}
                                        />
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

---------
Square.js
---------

export default function Square(props) {
    function uncover(e) {
        if (!props.hasMine && e.target.className !== 'white-square') {
            e.target.className = 'white-square';
            let right = document.getElementById(`square-${props.row}-${props.col + 1}`);
            let bottomRight = document.getElementById(`square-${props.row + 1}-${props.col + 1}`);
            let bottom = document.getElementById(`square-${props.row + 1}-${props.col}`);
            let bottomLeft = document.getElementById(`square-${props.row + 1}-${props.col - 1}`);
            let left = document.getElementById(`square-${props.row}-${props.col - 1}`);
            let topLeft = document.getElementById(`square-${props.row - 1}-${props.col - 1}`);
            let top = document.getElementById(`square-${props.row - 1}-${props.col}`);
            let topRight = document.getElementById(`square-${props.row - 1}-${props.col + 1}`);
            if (right) {
                right.click();
            }
            if (bottomRight) {
                bottomRight.click();
            }
            if (bottom) {
                bottom.click();
            }
            if (bottomLeft) {
                bottomLeft.click()
            }
            if (left) {
                left.click()
            }
            if (topLeft) {
                topLeft.click()
            }
            if (top) {
                top.click()
            }
            if (topRight) {
                topRight.click()
            }
        }
    }
    return (
        <div
            className={props.hasMine ? 'red-square' : 'grey-square'}
            id={props.id}
            onClick={uncover}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: That's not the React way. No `document.getElementById` or `element.click` should be used. You keep a state (`useState`) and then you render from props and that state. Use callbacks (`onClick`) to pass values to a parent component. Check some tutorials and implement more simple examples (a counter, for example) to get used to the concepts.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful